# auto increment with different department

Tags: vb.net

so this is my code for inserting files and what i need to autoincrement the codes but the thing is i cant use the id since it has so many department in just one table for example

```
OP-BLDG-16-0001
LP-LAND-16-0001
```

codename.Text = "" & codedepartment.Text & "-" & code1.Text & "-" & Now.Date.ToString("yy") & "-" & "00" & ""

So thats what i did to get first 3 info and i just have to set it into autoincrement

---

```
Try
dataB = "INSERT into assetpp ( [codes],[codedepartmentname]) VALUES ( '" & codename.Text & "','" & codedepartment.Text & "')"


            ConnDB()

            cmd = New OleDbCommand(dataB, conn)
            Dim i As Integer
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If i > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Add Succesfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Confirmation")
                tableassetpp()

            Else
                MsgBox("Failed to add Data", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Alert")

            End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: What  kind of database is at work here?

Comment: It is Microsoft Access 2007

Comment: that looks like there are 2-3 pieces of info in those "Ids".  Thats a bad idea because eventually, you will that info individually and because it is hard to create unique ones in a multi user system.  But it is easy to glue the info together so it *looks like* it is one field

Comment: what do you mean glue the info together and how will that work?

Comment: codename.Text = "" & codedepartment.Text & "-" & code1.Text & "-" & Now.Date.ToString("yy") & "-" & "00" & ""

So thats what i did to get first 3 info and i just have to set last 00  into autoincrement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Static cnt As Integer
        cnt = cnt + 1
        codename.Text = "" & codedepartment.Text & "-" & code1.Text & "-" & Now.Date.ToString("yy") & "-" & Format(cnt, "0000") & ""
```